# How do I install python pyRAPL module on MacOS?

Tags: install, python

How do I install python [pyRAPL](https://pypi.org/project/pyRAPL/#files) module on MacOS high sierra 10.13.6?

The following errors are coming up whenever I try to install. How do I solve it?

[image]

Comment: have you tried `pip3 install pyRAPL` or `python2 -m pip install pyRAPL` or `python3 -m pip install pyRAPL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pip3 install pyRAPL
```

Worked fine for me

If you have any errors try the following:

```
python3 -m pip install pyRAPL
```